# Normal distribution. Find the average

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

In a large group of patients, cholesterol level approximates a normal distribution N(μ, σ). Observed that 20% of the members of this group have a cholesterol level of less than 117.7mg/100ml and 8% had levels above 239mg/100ml.

What is the average, μ, of the normal distribution?

Comment: self-study? If so, add the tag and please read the wiki.

Comment: Routine bookwork type questions are classified as `self-study` (and should be tagged as such). The `self-study` tag wiki can be found [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please add the tag and modify your question to incorporate the requested information.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming this is a self-study question, here is a hint: $(\mu,\sigma)$ is determined by the system of two equations
$$\begin{cases} \Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{117.7-\mu\})=0.2 & \\ \Phi(\sigma^{-1}\{239-\mu\})=0.92 & \end{cases}$$
From there, you can proceed by identifying the $0.2$ and $0.92$ quantiles of the $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution, concluding by solving a system of two linear equations.